# Reporting toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ms-word, activex

I use the nice program [wordreport](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17953-wordreport) to generate Word reports in Matlab.  Typically I write a script and process 100+ datafiles, making plots and tables from each datafile that are then inserted into the Word document.  However the formatting options in wordreport are limited, for example you can't specify that a table is 3" wide and that the first row and column are in bold font.   If I was a whiz with ActiveX I could revise wordreport for more formatting options, but I haven't understood enough about ActiveX to succeed.  Alternatively, Matlab sells a toolbox for generating reports.   If you use the toolbox, what's your experience been - Worth the money?  Can you make a lot of formatting choices, and generate reports from within scripts/functions rather than with a GUI?

Comment: Can't comment on either. I usually write LaTeX files from Matlab which I then compile.

Comment: I second the LaTeX.  Especially if you have anything large (>50 pags) or if you have a document that will live for a long time.

Comment: Does LaTeX play nicely with Windows?   Ages ago I dabbled in LaTeX, including some command-line document generation from within Matlab, but that was when I had a unix machine.   The reporting solution must be robust for several different Windows users who will be running the Matlab reporting program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative for you to consider: OfficeDoc - reads/writes/formats MS Office documents (DOC/XLS/PPT) from within Matlab.

The free version: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15192-officedoc

The Pro version ($19.95): http://www.ymasoftware.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, especially since the other users of my reporting program are having trouble with wordreport crashing after generating 50+ plots.  The Matlab reporting toolbox must be pretty limited since no one seems to be using it for heavy duty report generation!

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to add some screenshots showing example documents to your Pro site to illustrate your program's many capabilities (or perhaps I missed it).